# Railstutorial.org 3rd ed. Listing 8.5: Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I've been working on getting my tests to pass from Ch. 9.2 (User Edit test) and I traced back to some problem in the log_in_as method created in ch 8 in the test_helper.

I pored over my code and compared it with the sample and everything looked okay.  I finally resorted to copying the code out of the book.  This got the tests to pass...but I can see no differences between the code i originally wrote and the copied.  So, my question is, what the hell *is* the difference between my code and his?  This only thing I can fathom is whitespace.  This has been a real stumper.  Any insights would be most appreciated.

Mine:

```
30   def log_in_as(user, options = {})                                                                                                                            
31     password    = options[:password]      || 'password'                                                                                                       
32     remember_me = options[:remember_me]   || '1'                                                                                                                
33     if integration_test?                                                                                                                                      
34       post login_path, session: { email:        user.email,                                                                                                    
35                                   passsword:    password,                                                                                                      
36                                   remember_me:  remember_me }                                                                                                  
37     else                                                                                                                                                         
38       session[:user_id] = user.id                                                                                                                                
39     end                                                                                                                                                        
40   end
```

His:

```
def log_in_as(user, options = {})
  password    = options[:password]    || 'password'
  remember_me = options[:remember_me] || '1'
  if integration_test?
    post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                password:    password,
                                remember_me: remember_me }
  else
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has 3*s in password on line 35:

```
    post login_path, session: { email:        user.email,
                                pass-s-word:    password,
                                remember_me:  remember_me }
```

should be

```
    post login_path, session: { email:       user.email,
                                password:    password,
                                remember_me: remember_me }
```